# Arrays: Comparing one array to another to find averages

Tags: java, arrays

Hey I'm trying to calculate the of a quiz by comparing two arrays. The two arrays set up are the correct answers and student answers of a quiz. I'm trying to get it to look like this:

Student Marks Average

Arnie Score: 4 Percentage: 0.8

This is because Arnie has got 4 questions correct out of 5 questions. The answers of the student and the correct answers are found in the text document which I already loaded onto an array on my code. The text document contains a 2D array with Arnie's answers in the form of chars and a 1D array containing the correct answers (also chars). There are more students but I would like some guidance on how to get the average for Arnie so I can do it for the rest of the names on my own.

Here is my code so far with the two arrays set up.

```
public class workingCode

{
    private static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void stuAnsOut(String arg []) throws IOException
    {
        File studentAns = new File("Ans_Stu.txt");
        Scanner stuAns = new Scanner(studentAns);

        String stuAnsString[] = new String[6];
        char stuAnsArray[][] = new char[3][5];
        String[] stuNameArray = new String[3];

        for (int i = 0; i<stuAnsString.length;i++)
        {
            stuAnsString[i]=stuAns.nextLine(); 
        }

        for (int i=0,j=0; i<stuAnsArray.length && j<stuAnsString.length;i++, j=j+2)
        {
            stuNameArray[i] = stuAnsString[j];      
        }

        for (int i=0,j=1; i<stuAnsArray.length && j<stuAnsString.length;i++, j=j+2)
        {
            stuAnsArray[i] = stuAnsString[j].toUpperCase().toCharArray();      
        }

        System.out.println("Student Answers: ");
        System.out.printf("%5s","Name");

        for (int i =0; i<1;i++)
        {
            for (int j =1; j<(stuAnsArray[i].length+1);j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%5s",j);
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%n"); 

        for (int i =0; i<stuAnsArray.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5s",stuNameArray[i]);
            for (int j=0;j<stuAnsArray[i].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%5s",stuAnsArray[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("%n"); 
        }
    }

    public static void corAnsOut(String arg []) throws IOException
    {
        File correctAns = new File("Ans_Cor.txt");
        Scanner corAns = new Scanner(correctAns);
        String corAnsString = corAns.next(); 

        char corAnsArray[] = new char[5];

        for (int i=0; i<corAnsArray.length;i++)
        {
            corAnsArray[i] = corAnsString.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Correct Answers: ");
        System.out.println(newline);

        for (int i =1; i<(corAnsArray.length+1);i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5s",i);
        }
        System.out.printf("%n"); 

        for (int i =0; i<corAnsArray.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%5s",corAnsArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("%n"); 
    }
}
```

I am not allowed to use ArrayLists, only Arrays. And please use the array names I already have in my code. Thanks!

Edit: This is what I got so far. But it is giving me an error:

```
public static void compareInteger(int corAnsArray [], int stuAnsArray[])
{double score =0;

for (int i = 0; i < stuAnsArray.length; i++)
{if(stuAnsArray[i] == corAnsArray[i])
score += 1.0;
}
 System.out.println(score/corAnsArray.length);

}
```

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: So the first part is getting the average of each student. So I'm supposed to output Arnie's score and the percentage they got. To do this I know I have to compare the correct answer array to the student answer array. How can this be done? Suppose I make another method, how can I call both arrays and find Arnie's score and calculate the average? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is create a class called Student

```
public class Student {
  private string studentName;
  private float marks; 
  private float average;

  // Getters & all parameter constructor 
}
```

Then change your working class to

```
public class workingCode
{
    private static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    public static void stuAnsOut(String arg []) throws IOException
    {
        File studentAns = new File("Ans_Stu.txt");
        Scanner stuAns = new Scanner(studentAns);
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while(stuAns.hasNext()) {
            string parts = stuAns.nextLine().split(" ");
            students.add(new Student(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]))
        }
        // At this point you have all the students in the List
    }
}
```

Now to calculate avg :

```
float total = 0;
for(Student s : students) {
   total += s.getMarks();
}
System.out.println("avg = " + total/students.size());
```

or

```
float total = 0;
for(Student s : students) {
   total += s.getAverage();
}
System.out.println("avg = " + total);
```

Comment: Okay but I am not allowed to use arraylists, only arrays.

Comment: @Nb179 should be fairly simple to change `List<Student>` to `Student[]`

Answer (score 0):

Code for comparing arrays (both for INT and String arrays):

```
public class Compare{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double averageInt;
        double averageString;
        int[] correctInt = {9,8,12,6,3,12,90}; //Correct answers
        int[] answerInt = {9,8,4,6,3,12,90}; //Student's answers
        String[] correctString = {"A","A","B","C"}; //Correct answers
        String[] answerString = {"A","C","B","C"}; //Student's answers
        Compare compare = new Compare();
        averageInt = compare.compareInteger(correctInt, answerInt);
        averageString = compare.compareString(correctString, answerString);
        System.out.println(averageInt);
        System.out.println(averageString);
    }

    public double compareInteger(int[] correct, int[] answer){ //Compares the int arrays
        double score = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < correct.length; i++){
            if(correct[i] == answer[i])
                score += 1.0;
        }
        return score/correct.length; //Returns average
    }

    public double compareString(String[] correct, String[] answer){ //Compares the String arrays
        double score = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < correct.length; i++){
            if(correct[i].equals(answer[i]))
                score += 1.0;
        }
        return score/correct.length; //Returns average
    }
}
```

I do not understand the marking system though. If you'd explain it more in-depth, I'd be more than happy to provide you with the code.

Comment: So the first number is the score and the next is the percentage. So for Arnie has 4 points and the percentage is 0.8 (4/5).